# How can I know if license of new version is added to the server

Tags: licensing

When a new Mathematica version is released (e.g 10.1,10.2,...) the server in my organization does not immediately update the license to the new version.
Previously, I had to contact the admin from time to time to check if they add the new version to the license server so that I can install the new version and use it.

This is sometimes boring when I have to contact the admin continuously.

Is there any way to check if license of new version is added to the license server.

For Example: I am currently running `10.3.1` and I want to check if `10.4` license is added to the server, how can I know that by myself without contacting the sever admin.

Thank you

Comment: Given that I suppose you are going to install the new version when you can use it, why not install it anyway and just try? If the license is not ready it will tell you and refuse to start, but you can still run the previous version as long as you used two different installation directories.